# Enum declaration not found when including containing header

Tags: c, c89

I have an enumerator type that is declared in a header file. I would like to use this in a c file that includes this header file. However when compiling I get an error that the enumerator type is not defined. I've tried copying the enumerator declaration to my source file but I get an error: "nested redefinition of ‘enum command_type’"

Could someone explain how to use the enumerator type in my file please? 
Thank you!

The enumerator:

```
//command-internals.h
enum command_type
  {
    AND_COMMAND,         // A && B
    SEQUENCE_COMMAND,    // A ; B
    OR_COMMAND,          // A || B
    PIPE_COMMAND,        // A | B
    SIMPLE_COMMAND,      // a simple command
    SUBSHELL_COMMAND,    // ( A )
  };
```

The usage:

```
//#include "command-internals.h"
command_type scan(char *buffer)
...
```

The error: `error: unknown type name ‘command_type’`

Answer (score 2):

Your prototype should read:

```
enum command_type scan(char *buffer);
```

Since you didn't put a `typedef` on the enum declaration.

Comment: Yep that did it. Sorry I guess this is a pretty dumb question. Thanks for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1):

With your code compiler cannot understand what is the the *type* of `command_type`.
One will typically use a `typedef`:

**//Header file**

```
typedef enum {....} command_type;
```

**//C File**

```
command_type scan(char *buffer)
```

With this you don't have to remember to keep adding an `enum` everywhere again.